# Viewing data from db in HTML using Zend1

Tags: html, database, zend-framework

I am viewing data from the database. I am using a Varchar (500). The problem is that in the view there are no enters displayed in my text, but in my page source there will be enters displayed, it should be like a list. How can I display the enters in the view like the page source?

This is my code:

Controller

```
        $select = $cateringDb->select()
            ->setIntegrityCheck(false)
            ->from($cateringDb);

        $cateringen = $cateringDb->fetchAll($select);
        $this->view->cateringen = $cateringen;
```

View

```
        foreach ($this->cateringen as $cateringen)
        {
            echo $this->escape($cateringen->catering);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert the newlines into HTML line breaks. PHP has [a function for this](http://www.php.net/nl2br):

```
foreach ($this->cateringen as $cateringen)
{
    echo nl2br($this->escape($cateringen->catering));
}
```